# WPF Style Binding to other Control

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml

I try to create a reusable `Style` in my `Styles.xaml` for multiple `Datagrids`. By now I have the following `Style` which actually with `Dummydata`, works (shows only active records as expected):

```
   <Style x:Key="dgrstyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=chb_active, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True" />
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Active}" Value="False" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            </MultiDataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

But my problems I are the following:

1. I have to name every `checkbox` as *chb_active* --> could work for now, but what if I have multiple DG in one `View`?
2. *Active* is a Binding to a column in the data. But later it could have possibly have another/different names.

So: how can I make the two bindings more dynamic or define them in the `Datagrid` definition? Otherwise I'd possibly have to create a similar style for each `datagrid(row)` alone.

I also read something about **Ancestor** but can't see how to use it in this case. Would be happy to get some help, when there is a way to solve that.